# In Wire is there a way to inject named dependency?

Tags: go, dependency-injection

This is required by a scenario that one business Service Object struct depends on multiple storages, say, *sql.DB pointing to different MySQL backend.

Note that type is probably insufficient to determine which provider here cos they are all *sql.DB. I’m wondering if named dependency is the recommended way & does wire support it?

Comment: https://github.com/google/wire/blob/main/docs/faq.md#what-if-my-dependency-graph-has-two-dependencies-of-the-same-type

I found this solution and personally feel it’s a bit ugly to wrap and unwrap. Now wondering if any better way to achieve it. Or any concern is missed?